# Read files from a folder with OpenMP and fill a list of elements

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'd like to read files from fylesystem in parallel with OpenMP and populate a thread-shared list.
With `shared` I specify which variable are shared among threads, with  `private` the private index and then I `schedule` the iteration among the threads statically.

The shared list `imageList` is where I want to append each file I just read from filesystem. It has been passed as a pointer to the current method.

Sometimes the inner `for` loop fails during `imageList->append(tmpFile);` causing a `corrupted double-linked list` error.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong with OpenMP since, if I remove the parallelization, the code works perfectly.

Have you got any hint?

Thank you

```
void ImageHandler::readImagesFromDir(QList< QPair<QString, cv::Mat>>* imageList) 

// folderSize, fileName list previously defined.
....
int index, chunk = 1;
 // I will read from HD and I'd like to populate imageList
 // imageList and chunk are shared among threads while index not
#pragma omp parallel shared(imageList, chunk) private(index)
{
    // setting a static schedule
    #pragma omp for schedule(static, chunk) nowait
    for (index = 0; index < folderSize; ++index)
    {
        // Getting image's file name
        std::string fn = fileName[index];

        // Reading image and storing it in a Matrix
        cv::Mat im = cv::imread(fileName[index], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        if (im.empty()) continue;

        // Packing my QPair with image's name and related RGB matrix
        QPair<QString, cv::Mat> tmpFile;
        tmpFile.first = QString::fromStdString(fn);
        tmpFile.second = im;

        // FAILING HERE while populating imageList
        imageList->append(tmpFile);

    }
}   /* end of parallel region */
```

Comment: Add `#pragma omp critical` before the offending line

Comment: I really wouldn't read files in parallel using OpenMP.  Without the right hardware (if you had a parallel file system you'd know it so I'm assuming you don't have one) you're just programming for extra contention as the threads fight for the read/write head.  I think you'll get better performance reading the files before the `parallel` section.

Comment: @Gilles  thanks it worked,   I gained 3x in reading.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, yes I know it's not a best practice, but I notice that I can still gain something in reading with OpenMP. Thank you